# Why symfony 1.2 is throwing Out of Memory error?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony1, symfony-1.2

I'm trying to generate Forms and Models files in symfony from command prompt but when i run `php symfony propel:build-model` it throws the below error

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1978925056) (tried to allocate
>   40 bytes) in
>   D:\xampp-old\htdocs\symfony_v1.2\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfPropelPlugin\lib\vendor\propel-generator\classes\propel\engine\builder\om\php5\PHP5ObjectBuilder.php on line 133

I have changed memory limit in php.ini to `memory_limit = 128M`

But still it's throwing the above error.

Thanks

Comment: symfony 1.2 is not supported anymore ! please upgrade to 4.1 or at least 3.4 LTS
https://symfony.com/roadmap

Comment: @azjezz Symfony 1 is a completely different product than Symfony 2,3,4.  Yes, upgrading is a good idea but it's probably legacy code and a complete rewrite can be challenging.

Comment: @Cerad ik ! but no documentation is available anymore, even the code is not on github ~ so its not easy  to guess whats going on there

Comment: Of course it is not easy to guess the issue from a rather poorly written question.  There are however a gazillion questions on how to troubleshoot out of memory configuration errors.

Comment: This is your best bet for symfony 1 compatibility. https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony1/symfony1 It offers a ton of improvement over the final versions of 1.2 - 1.4.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry but check your disk space, it looks like the available disk space for disk D(where xampp is installed) is very small.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with disk space.  It is a memory issue.

Comment: No bro there is 80GB+ available free.

Comment: Okay, then the best advice would be to create all those models and controllers manually, that's if you can't migrate to an LTS version like 3.4